# Eclipse Kepler - PHP Code completion not working

Tags: php, eclipse, project, aptana, code-completion

Today i've downloaded Eclipse Kepler and i've noticed that PHP code completion is not working anymore.
when i type the first letters of a standard php function then press CTRL+Space, it gives me an empty list ("No Default Proposal").
This used to work with the older version (i was using Juno) and i've made no modification.

I've already tried removing the PHP nature and adding it again (through Right Click => Configure => Add PHP Support), but it didn't help.

In both versions the only plugin i have installed is Aptana Studio 3.5.0 (nightly build) but i'm using Eclipse's editor for PHP, not Aptana's, nor i'm using Aptana's PHP nature, but Eclipse's

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try clearing the PDT index.  See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/489559/1065653/#msg_1065653

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem indeed

Comment: I've replied in the newsgroup asking about that.  No response so far.

Comment: This was the solution. I later saw this error in Eclipse's log (which explains how the nice Toshiro guy was able to quickly post a fix in their forums) when running down other Kepler oddities:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file "workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/model.data.db - please convert the database to a SQL script and re-create it." [90048-168]

Answer (score 5):

One more hint, because the solution mentioned above did not help for me:
After additionally installing "Dynamic Languages Toolkit Core Frameworks", content assist works again.

Comment: Thanks, @Baster!  Also, after I completed the installation of "Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Core Frameworks", installation of PHP PDT succeeded as well.